# Saving plot .pdf to working directory in R for a Mac

Tags: r, data-visualization, effects

I am working on a MacBook Pro OSX 10.12.5 and R 3.4.0.

I have run a simple linear regression (and lmer plots, but one step at a time) utilizing the effects package.

It is a common issue that R will crash when trying to utilize any GUI commands on a Mac. I was using the grab application then converting to a pdf but that is cumbersome.  I am looking for something that will save my plot as a .pdf to my working directory as a work around to the Mac bug. I have seen packages like knir however, that is not helpful or I am doing something wrong.

is there an elegant solution?

example of my plot code below:

```
    eff.IV <- allEffects(mod)
    plot(eff.IV[1], ylab= "DV continuous 1:10", xlab="IV, 3 levels")
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
eff.IV <- allEffects(mod)
pdf("filename.pdf")
plot(eff.IV[1], ylab= "DV continuous 1:10", xlab="IV, 3 levels")
dev.off()
```

Comment: Btw, I know folks who do R programming on a Mac so these highly limiting bugs and crashes you speak of are strange.

Comment: You're welcome. Since it answers your question, you can "accept" it as an answer.

Comment: It does it to me every time.  There are several comments on this on various boards.... the typical reply is "use R-Studio."

example:  (this is exactly what happens to me even with the latest version.)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155623/r-freezes-hangs-in-mac-os-x-yosemite

Comment: I tried immediately it said wait 3 minutes.  Just accepted thanks!!

Comment: Thanks. I've learnt something new too - wait three minutes . Well, I have Mac R friends who use Rstudio. You could look up an installation guide online that may mention some of the issues you're dealing with. Rstudio truly saves you a tonne of effort.

Comment: That's definitely in the works (resolving the Rstudio issue)....  but not till September!  Thanks, again!